# Creating a copy constructor: which way is more efficient?

Tags: java, copy-constructor

Let's say I create a copy constructor to make a copy of a Party object.
My original constructor looks like this:

```
public Party(LocalDate date, String location, String host) {
    this.date = date;
    this.location = location;
    this.host = host;
}
```

Now I create a copy constructor:

```
public Party(Party p){
```

Now I have two options. Either I can do this:

```
this(p.date, p.location, p.host)}
```

Or I can do this:

```
this(p.getDate(), p.getLocation(), p.getHost()}
```

Is one way more advisable than the other? or no difference?

Comment: Is the accepted answer to that question saying that really you can do either way and it doesn't make a difference efficiency wise?

Comment: Yes, I would not worry about efficiency in this instance. Really, it is about personal preference. I, for one, prefer the first where you access the field directly.